# Fragmented MP4 support in Windows Media Foundation

Tags: mp4, ms-media-foundation

Can anyone please provide any notes regarding the support for playback of fragmented MP4 files in Windows Media Foundation? I have a proper fragmented MP4 file (ffplay, vlc, chrome are all happy with it). However on Windows 7 neither Windows Media Player, nor IE 11, nor Qt with WMF backend are able to play it ( `IMFSourceResolver::CreateObjectFromURL` returns `MF_E_UNSUPPORTED_BYTESTREAM_TYPE`) however on Windows 10 Windows Media Player, IE and Edge are all happy with the file. Is there something that can be installed on Windows 7 to obtain the same behaivor? I had the notion that IE11 had the support for HTML5 video and thus for fragmented MP4 files as well, however seems that this asumption has been wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft added support for fragmental MP4 files in Windows 8. To my best knowledge there has been no installable update for Windows 7 to receive similar functionality.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757763#WINDOWS_8_UPDATES_TO_MPEG-4_SOURCE_AND_SINK):

> #### Windows 8 updates to MPEG-4 source and sink
>
> [...]
>
> - Movie fragments ('moof') is supported in Windows 8 MPEG-4 source and sink, but 'mfra' is not.
>     [...]
> - Files larger than 4 GB are supported in Windows 8 MPEG-4 sink for non-fragmental MP4.
>     [...]
> - 3D information in AVC configuration record is supported for non-fragmental MP4.

Comment: I had figured this out since then by myself - but still counts:)

Comment: that doesn't change anything to the media MSIE supports ... or does it ?